# Different setStroke color per UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I want to set an different stroke color for each UIBezierPath section. But the order is totally wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

This is what I want:

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

It seems like that the order is wrong. Is there a way to "bind" the color to the bezierPath and append that to the context? My code is below. Thanks!

```
      let size = CGSize(width: 134, height:51)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, width: 126, height: 50), cornerRadius: 3)
    UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1
    rectanglePath.stroke()
    let clipPath: CGPath = rectanglePath.cgPath
    context?.addPath(clipPath)

    //// Rectangle 2 Drawing
    let rectangle2Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 3, y: 3, width: 121, height: 45), cornerRadius: 3)
    UIColor.green.setFill()
    rectangle2Path.fill()
    let clipPathh: CGPath = rectangle2Path.cgPath
    context?.addPath(clipPathh)

    let rectangle3Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 128, y: 18, width: 6, height: 14), byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3))
    UIColor.gray.setFill()
    rectangle3Path.fill()
    let clipPathhh: CGPath = rectangle3Path.cgPath
    context?.addPath(clipPathhh)

    context?.closePath()

    // Convert to UIImage
    let cgimage = context!.makeImage();
    let uiimage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage!)

    // End the graphics context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    image.image = uiimage;
```

Comment: I did a pretty rough copy/paste of your code into a new project with a UIImageView thrown in via IB. I'm getting the correct result. Light gray border around a green fill. Not sure why it works for me. Now, if what you really want is a gray border outside a white border which has a green fill, you may need a third path for the white.

Comment: Mhh, did you paste it into the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes. Again, a rough and quick copy/past. For bezier paths you usually want things in a view's drawRect.

Comment: If you remove the code related to rectangle3path you'll have a light gray border around a green fill. It looks like it's that rectanlge3path (which is a very small rect with light gray fill that is wrong. Also, if you want a white border between the gray one and the green fill, insert another rect between PATHS #1 AND #2.

Comment: Yes that is correct. But I don't know what is going wrong with rectangle3path. It looks like it overrides all the colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. Been a while since I worked with bezier paths, but a bit of playing around found the issue - it's all in the sequence. The code should be:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 134, height:51)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

//// Rectangle Drawing
let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, width: 126, height: 50), cornerRadius: 3)
UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1
let clipPath: CGPath = rectanglePath.cgPath
context?.addPath(clipPath)
rectanglePath.stroke()

//// Rectangle 2 Drawing
let rectangle2Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 3, y: 3, width: 121, height: 45), cornerRadius: 3)

UIColor.green.setFill()
let clipPathh: CGPath = rectangle2Path.cgPath
context?.addPath(clipPathh)
rectangle2Path.fill()

let rectangle3Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 128, y: 18, width: 6, height: 14), byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3))
UIColor.gray.setFill()
let clipPathhh: CGPath = rectangle3Path.cgPath
context?.addPath(clipPathhh)
rectangle3Path.fill()

// Convert to UIImage
let cgimage = context!.makeImage();
let uiimage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage!)

// End the graphics context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


imageView.image = uiimage;
```

Note that you do the fill/stroke **after** adding the path to the context. Also, note that the closePath call has no impact, as you are already giving the entire path by defining rects.